# Equivalent implicit operators: why are they legal?

Tags: c#, .net, implicit, ambiguity, implicit-conversion

### Update!

*See my dissection of a portion of the C# spec below; I think I must be missing something, because to **me** it looks like the behavior I'm describing in this question actually violates the spec.*

### Update 2!

*OK, upon further reflection, and based on some comments, I think I now understand what's going on. The words "source type" in the spec refer to the type being converted **from** -- i.e., `Type2` in my example below -- which simply means that the compiler is able to narrow the candidates down to the two operators defined (since `Type2` is the source type for both). However, it cannot narrow the choices any further. So the key words in the spec (as it applies to this question) are **"source type"**, which I previously misinterpreted (I think) to mean "declaring type."*

---

### Original Question

Say I have these types defined:

```
class Type0
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public Type0(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

class Type1 : Type0
{
    public Type1(string value) : base(value) { }

    public static implicit operator Type1(Type2 other)
    {
        return new Type1("Converted using Type1's operator.");
    }
}

class Type2 : Type0
{
    public Type2(string value) : base(value) { }

    public static implicit operator Type1(Type2 other)
    {
        return new Type1("Converted using Type2's operator.");
    }
}
```

Then say I do this:

```
Type2 t2 = new Type2("B");
Type1 t1 = t2;
```

Obviously this is ambiguous, as it is not clear which `implicit` operator should be used. My question is -- since I cannot see **any** way to resolve this ambiguity (it isn't like I can perform some explicit cast to clarify which version I want), and yet the class definitions above do compile -- **why would the compiler allow those matching `implicit` operators at all?**

---

### Dissection

OK, I'm going to step through the excerpt of the C# spec quoted by Hans Passant in an attempt to make sense of this.

> Find the set of types, D, from which
>   user-defined conversion operators will
>   be considered. This set consists of S
>   (if S is a class or struct), the base
>   classes of S (if S is a class), and T
>   (if T is a class or struct).

We're converting *from* `Type2` (**S**) *to* `Type1` (**T**). So it seems that here **D** would include all three types in the example: `Type0` (because it is a base class of **S**), `Type1` (**T**) and `Type2` (**S**).

> Find the set of applicable
>   user-defined conversion operators, U.
>   This set consists of the user-defined
>   implicit conversion operators declared
>   by the classes or structs in D that
>   convert from a type encompassing S to
>   a type encompassed by T. If U is
>   empty, the conversion is undefined and
>   a compile-time error occurs.

All right, we've got two operators satisfying these conditions. The version declared in `Type1` meets the requirements because `Type1` is in **D** and it converts from `Type2` (which obviously encompasses **S**) to `Type1` (which is obviously encompassed by **T**). The version in `Type2` *also* meets the requirements for exactly the same reasons. So **U** includes both of these operators.

Lastly, with respect to finding the most specific "source type" **SX** of the operators in **U**:

> **If any of the operators in U convert from S, then SX is S.**

Now, *both* operators in **U** convert from **S** -- so this tells me that **SX** is **S**.

**Doesn't this mean that the `Type2` version should be used?**

But wait! I'm confused!

Couldn't I have **only** defined `Type1`'s version of the operator, in which case, the only remaining candidate would be `Type1`'s version, and yet according to the spec **SX** would be `Type2`? This seems like a possible scenario in which the spec mandates something impossible (namely, that the conversion declared in `Type2` should be used when in fact it does not exist).

Comment: One declaration probably takes precedence over the other. Which one does the compiler choose?

Comment: @dtb: It allows the class definitions, but it does not allow the example code at the bottom. It states that there are ambiguous user defined conversions. In other words, it allows for the code to compile, but never for it to be *used*.

Comment: I'll point out that it does exactly the same thing if there are multiple user-defined explicit conversions.

Comment: @mquander: Well, at least it's consistent, then ;)

Comment: It probably doesn't check because (a) it would be fine if the two classes were in different namespaces and (b) it cannot know if a conflicting declaration is in the same namespace but in a different assembly. So it checks when you use it instead when you declare it.

Comment: @dtb: That makes sense, and actually did occur to me shortly after posting the question. One other (very dubious) way I discovered to disambiguate the two operator definitions is by using reflection -- `typeof(Type1).GetMethod("op_Implicit").Invoke([blah blah])`. So there's that, too ;) If you were to turn that comment into an answer I'd accept it, as I imagine it's the most sensible explanation.

Comment: @dtb: **Actually**, from what [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561619/equivalent-implicit-operators-why-are-they-legal/3561905#3561905) is saying, it sounds like the conversion defined by `Type2` *should* take precedence. Now I'm really confused...

Comment: This is another reason why you should avoid using implicit cast operators:)

Comment: No, I got that wrong.  The SX set does contain both conversions.  Sorry for getting you off the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't really want it to be a compile-time error just to define conversions which *might* cause ambiguity. Suppose that we alter Type0 to store a double, and for some reason we want to provide separate conversions to signed integer and unsigned integer.

```
class Type0
{
    public double Value { get; private set; }

    public Type0(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Int32(Type0 other)
    {
        return (Int32)other.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator UInt32(Type0 other)
    {
        return (UInt32)Math.Abs(other.Value);
    }

}
```

This compiles fine, and I can use use both conversions with

```
Type0 t = new Type0(0.9);
int i = t;
UInt32 u = t;
```

However, it's a compile error to try `float f = t` because either of the implicit conversions could be used to get to an integer type which can then be converted to float.

We only want the compiler to complain about these more complex ambiguities when they're actually used, since we'd like the Type0 above to compile. For consistency, the simpler ambiguity should also cause an error at the point you use it rather than when you define it.

**EDIT**

Since Hans removed his answer which quoted the spec, here's a quick run through the part of the C# spec that determines whether a conversion is ambiguous, having defined U to be the set of all the conversions which could possibly do the job:

> - Find the most specific source type, SX, of the operators in U:
>
>   - If any of the operators in U convert from S, then SX is S.
>   - Otherwise, SX is the most encompassed type in the combined set of target types of the operators in U. If no most encompassed type can be found, then the conversion is ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs.

Paraphrased, we prefer a conversion which converts directly from S, otherwise we prefer the type which is "easiest" to convert S to. In both examples, we have two conversions from S available. If there were no conversions from `Type2`, we'd prefer a conversion from `Type0` over one from `object`. If no one type is obviously the better choice to convert from, we fail here.

> - Find the most specific target type, TX, of the operators in U:
>
>   - If any of the operators in U convert to T, then TX is T.
>   - Otherwise, TX is the most encompassing type in the combined set of target types of the operators in U. If no most encompassing type can be found, then the conversion is ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs.

Again, we'd prefer to convert directly to T, but we'll settle for the type that's "easiest" to convert to T. In Dan's example, we have two conversions to T available. In my example, the possible targets are `Int32` and `UInt32`, and neither is a better match than the other, so this is where the conversion fails. The compiler has no way to know whether `float f = t` means `float f = (float)(Int32)t` or `float f = (float)(UInt32)t`.

> - If U contains exactly one user-defined conversion operator that converts from SX to TX, then this is the most specific conversion operator. If no such operator exists, or if more than one such operator exists, then the conversion is ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs.

In Dan's example, we fail here because we have two conversions left from SX to TX. We could have no conversions from SX to TX if we chose different conversions when deciding SX and TX. For example, if we had a `Type1a` derived from `Type1`, then we might have conversions from `Type2` to `Type1a` and from `Type0` to `Type1` These would still give us SX=Type2 and TX=Type1, but we don't actually have any conversion from Type2 to Type1. This is OK, because this really is ambiguous. The compiler doesn't know whether to convert Type2 to Type1a and then cast to Type1, or cast to Type0 first so that it can use that conversion to Type1.

Comment: OK, I like this explanation. I also like the comment you provided to Hans's (now deleted) answer -- would you be up for incorporating the content of that comment into this answer? Either way, I feel this is worthy of acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, it can't be prohibitted with complete success. You and I could publish two assemblies. They we could start using each other's assembles, while updating our own. Then we could each provide implicit casts between types defined in each assembly. Only when we release the next version, could this be caught, rather than at compile time.

There's an advantage in not trying to ban things that can't be banned, as it makes for clarity and consistency (and there's a lesson for legislators in that).